# Java - Importing from Folders in Same Directory on Mac

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I am trying to import the javazoom.jl package into a program and have been trying to do so for hours now after trying different things that I found on the web. I have added both the associated JAR file and the javazoom folder to /Library/Java/Extensions/ (this is on a mac). I have also added these to the directory containing the program code. I have tried adding these to the classpath in a session of the Terminal, but that also has not worked.

The error message that I receive is:

```
    Runner.java:4: package javazoom.jl does not exist
    import javazoom.jl.*;
    ^
    1 error
```

I am compiling from the Terminal with javac. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using an IDE? Also, a build tool such as Maven? It's entirely possible to do what you want without them, but there are _better ways to solve your problem_ (namely, a build tool and an IDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the directory that directly contains the "javazoom" subdirectory?

```
javac -cp . YourClass.java
```

Or

```
javac -cp .;/path/to/jar/containing/javazoom YourClass.java
```

Does any of these commands work?

Comment: Correct, I am on the directory that directly contains the javazoom subdirectory. The first command did not work. For the second command, if I am in the directory that directly contains the jar, should I enter javac -cp .;j1.0.1.jar YourClass.java ? (j1.0.1.jar is the name of this jar.) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, try to do this. If you have any problems, refer to current path with .: `javac -cp .;./j1.0.1.jar YourClass.java`

Comment: Okay, I have something different now, after trying the second command. I type in: javac -cp .;./jl1.0.1.jar YourClass.java. I get a lot of information about the Usage of javac. I also get the following errors: ./jl1.0.1.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
./jl1.0.1.jar: line 2: b?p9: command not found
./jl1.0.1.jar: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'. Does this mean that my jar file is not right?

Comment: Sorry... Since you are on Mac, you should use `:` instead of `;`. `javac -cp .:./j1.0.1.jar YourClass.java`

Comment: Okay, thanks. Now I type in: javac -cp .:./jl1.0.1.jar Runner.java. I receive the same error that I specified in the opening post... Am I importing the wrong thing? How would I know?

Comment: A JAR is basically a ZIP file that contains classes. If you open the JAR with any ZIP reader (or I believe that you can rename the .jar to .zip and open it in Finder), can you see if there is a path named `javazoom` with a subdirectory named `jl` there, with the .class files that you want to use?

Comment: Well, I believe that I was importing something incorrectly. I changed my import statement to read: import javazoom.jl.player.Player as I just saw elsewhere on the Internet, and my code now compiles. This is my first question on StackOverFlow, so could you please let me know whether I should tick your answer or add a reply and explain how I solved the problem?

Comment: I think you can add and accept a reply in your own question. Glad it worked!

Comment: I made a very silly mistake ... I apparently did not have the correct import statement. For those looking for what to import for javazoom, import specific class files that you need. For instance, I replaced:

        import javazoom.jl.*;

with

        import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

As for the classpath, it seems that using the second command given by Bruno or placing the jar and the javazoom subdirectory in /Library/Java/Extensions work. (Both the jar and the subdirectory may not be necessary; I have not experimented to that extent.)